# Persisting state for VirtualFiles in IntelliJ IDEA plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

VFS documentation specifically lists ["Providing a possibility to associate additional persistent data with a file in the VFS"](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/virtual_file_system.html) as a feature.

However, it doesn't say *how* to persist the data across IDEA restarts and I didn't manage to find it by exploring the API. I thought that perhaps the data managed by `putUserData`/`getUserData` would be automatically persistent for `VirtualFile`s, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need [FileAttribute](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/907312838e0fdb795b12fce5ff89dddde16f04ec/platform/platform-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/vfs/newvfs/FileAttribute.java#L34-L34) instead.

See the usage in [LastUnchangedContentTracker](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/c4c0770ba6b5e702e871fefd309c9741f9e49dd4/platform/vcs-impl/src/com/intellij/openapi/vcs/changes/LastUnchangedContentTracker.java#L37-L37) for example.